# Resolve "7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission" when calling FirestoreAdminClient.exportDocuments

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, authorization, firebase-admin

This is how we are authenticating and calling the FirestoreAdminClient.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

const pathToServiceAccountKeyFile = '/path/to/service/account/key.json';

const serviceAccountKeyJSON = fs
  .readFileSync(pathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
  .toString();

const serviceAccountKeyObject = JSON.parse(serviceAccountKeyJSON);

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKeyObject)
});

const adminClient = new firebaseAdmin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient({
  keyFilename: pathToServiceAccountKeyFile
});

adminClient
  .exportDocuments({
    name: adminClient.databasePath('firebase-test-project-id', '(default)'),
    outputUriPrefix: 'gs://firebase-test-project-backups'
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response));
```

This is the output of the console.log statement.

```
7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

  at Object.callErrorFromStatus (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
  at Http2CallStream.call.on (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
  at process.nextTick (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:75:22)
```

This is where we generated the service account key.

[image]

References:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html

Comment: The code you're showing is not using the Firebase Admin SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: @DougStevenson The question is now using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Did you find an answer to this? I'm having a very similar problem. I've added all sorts of IAM roles to my `firebase-admin` and still not working. My question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032943/trying-to-access-firestoreadminclient-from-cloud-run-service-using-firebase-admi)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant additional permissions to your Service Accounts if you created the Service Account via the Firebase Console. The list of required permissions for data import and export via the Firestore Admin API is listed here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: While that is useful (+1), it is not the answer, because the Firebase Admin SDK account that we are using still does not work locally after we give it the Firebase Project Owner role (which is the same role that the successful `firebase login` user has). We set that role via the IAM page in the Google Cloud Console. The documentation linked in your answer says, *"If you are the project owner, your account has the required permissions."*

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me to identify and resolve the issue.

First, check the logs to see which service account is trying to run the function:
[image]

Then go to **IAM & Admin -> IAM** and find the service account from the previous step. Click on edit, select **+ADD ANOTHER ROLE** and type **Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin**.

[image]