# Trying to access FirestoreAdminClient from Cloud Run service using firebase-admin. ERROR: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I've got the following code for a an API endpoint that is supposed to trigger a Firestore backup using `firebase-admin`.

This is how I'm initializing `firebase-admin`;

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT as admin.ServiceAccount
)});
```

The service account key is a JSON I've downloaded using the default `firebase-admin` service account:

[image]

This is the `backup.ts` API request handler.

```
export const backupData: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const PROJECT_ID = process.env.PROJECT_ID;
    
    const client = new admin.firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();
    const DB_NAME = client.databasePath(PROJECT_ID, "(default)");

    const BUCKET = `gs://${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`;
    const FOLDER = `firestore-backup`;
    const FULL_PATH = `${BUCKET}/${FOLDER}`;

    const responses = await client.exportDocuments({
      name: DB_NAME,
      outputUriPrefix: FULL_PATH,
      collectionIds: [] // CAN LIST SPECIFIC COLLECTIONS
    });

    const response = responses[0];
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  } else 
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.error(err.message || DEFAULT_ERROR_MSG);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
};
```

The weird thing is:

It works perfectly on my dev environment. I mean, I run my local server and hit `localhost:8080/api/backup` (which is the correct endpoint) and everything works correctly and the backup is triggered.

But after I deploy it to my `cloud run` service, it no longer works.

This is the error I'm getting on my cloud run service:

> 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission

Do I need to add more permissions to that service account? But why does it work with that very same service account on my local dev environment? Should I not use a service account when I'm initializing it on my cloud run service? Don't know what to do here.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I've just tried to initialize it like this, but got the same results:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(SERVICE_ACCOUNT),
  databaseURL: `https://${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`,
  storageBucket: `${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`
});
```

Also, just followed [this doc tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions) and added these roles both to my `firebase-admin` and `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. Still not working:

- `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin`
- `Storage Admin`

**UPDATE 2:**

Following [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), I've just tried to initialize the `firebase-admin` without any parameters. Still same result:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Following the previous docs and [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles), I've added the IAM roles of `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin` and `Storage Admin` to my `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` service account. Still same results.

---

**CONCLUSION**

It just worked. But I've done so many attempts that I'm not really sure of what made it work. I'm guessing it was what I did on **UPDATE 3**. Will check that out and answer tomorrow.

Comment: You seem to be on the correct track. My service account has "storage legacy object owner" on the bucket and the following roles on the service account: `storage bucket list`, `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin`, `Cloud Datastore User`. A collection-based backup is done daily.  I see you have it working. Perhaps at this point setup a new service account to try and get least privileges set.

Comment: It takes less than a minute up to 7 minutes for IAM permissions to [propagate](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#access_revoke) so that could explain things if your 3rd update fixed the issue.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo That is probably what happened, indeed. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Took me a day to figure this out, but yeah. `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin` is what got it working for me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can confirm that `UPDATE 3` that I described on the question did the trick. Because I've reverted the changes I made on `UPDATE 1 and 2` and it's still working fine.

It seems that while on my local environment, `firebase-admin` is using the `firebase-adminsdk@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com` service account to call the `FirestoreAdminClient` API. That's why it works I guess. Or maybe it's using my `gcloud` logged account which is my `owner` email. I'm not really sure.

But once you are in Cloud Run environment, even though `firebase-admin` is being initialized with that very same service account, it seems that it kind of overrides that and uses the `xxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. So that's the one that needs the permissions.

I got that idea from [Cloud Run Service Identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles) and [Cloud Run IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles), that says:

[image]

And the roles needed I got from: [Firebase DOCS - Scheduled exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions):

[image]

This is the final config:

[image]

Comment: Saved My Day. Thank you.

For anyone having issues with permissions in cloud run. In IAM & Admin, Add permissions to ```xxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com``` and redeploy your service